# Printing out two separate tables into the same list

Tags: python, sqlite

I am attempting to print one list of results from two tables. Here are my tables:

```
cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS measures(
rainID DATE PRIMARY KEY,
rain FLOAT (15,2) NOT NULL,
level_of_dam FLOAT (15,2) NOT NULL,
level_of_lochan FLOAT (15,2) NOT NULL);
''')
db.commit()

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS turbine(
rainID DATE PRIMARY KEY,
pressure FLOAT (20,3) NOT NULL,
power FLOAT (20,3) NOT NULL,
deflector VARCHAR (5),
electricity FLOAT (20,3) NOT NULL);
''')
db.commit()
```

I am using this to 'get' the measures:

```
def getMeasures():
    with sqlite3.connect ("rainfall123.db") as db:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM measures,turbine")
        all_data = cursor.fetchall()
        all_data1 = (['Date','Rainfall','Dam','Lochan'])
        dash = '-' * 41
        for i in range(len(all_data)):
            if i == 0:
                print(dash)
                print('{:<10s}{:>10s}{:>5s}{:>14s}'.format(all_data1[0],all_data1[1],all_data1[2],all_data1[3]))
                print(dash)
            else:
                print('{:<12s}{:>4s}{:>12s}{:>12s}'.format(all_data[i][0],all_data[i][1],all_data[i][2],all_data[i][3]))
```

At the moment I can print out the first table, I have tried several things to attach both of them together - but separately - I would appreciate some help.

Ideally what I want is to be able to print out both tables into the same printed table.

Comment: Could please provide your attempts and also an example for the desired output?

Comment: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date        Rainfall  Dam        Lochan     Pressure     Power      Deflector     Elec
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
With the dates, rainfall, dam etc... underneath this. But Pressure, power deflector and electricity are in a different table from date, rainfall, dam, lochan.

Answer (score 0):

With your SQL SELECT statement you will get following result

```
rainID | rain |  level_of_dam | level_of_lochan | rainID | pressure | power | deflector | electricity
```

But with `getMeasures()`  you only call the first 3 items of each row and so you miss the data other data.

I think what you want to do is to get the correspondent data from your tables where the rainID are equal. So you need to perform an **Inner Join**.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM measures INNER JOIN turbine ON measures.rainID = turbine.rainID")
```

Now you need to call all cells from a row. Which would be `all_data[i][0]` to `all_data[i][8]`